# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError during RecyclerView scrolling

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have `RecyclerView`, which has another items inside. Each `RecyclerView` item has list of other items which are shown bellow as subitems if I **click** item in `RecyclerView`. To **avoid nested RecyclerView** thing, I iterate over these items in `onBindViewHolder()` and I add them to **empty LinearLayout** inflating subitem layout.

`OutOfMemory` error occurs as I **scroll down**, `because there can be 1000 items and each item could have 1000 subitems.` In my app its list of orders and if I click item from this list, list of ordered parts are shown one by one.

How to fix this issue. Also scrolling became laggy. I'm using Glide API to cache images, but this error still occurs.

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.order_recycler_view).apply {

            setHasFixedSize(true)

            // use a linear layout manager
            layoutManager = viewManager

            // specify an viewAdapter (see also next example)
            adapter = viewAdapter

            //set cache for rv
            setItemViewCacheSize(50)
            isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
            drawingCacheQuality = View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH


        }
```

inside RVAdapter onBindViewHolder():

```
for(orderItem in it.itemList){
                    val contentLayout: View = LayoutInflater.from(holder.itemView.context).inflate(R.layout.ordered_list_item_layout, null, false)

                    fillItemView(contentLayout, orderItem, res)

                holder.orderContentLayout.addView(contentLayout)
            }
```

FillItemView method:

```
    private fun fillItemView(contentLayout: View, orderItem: OrderedItem, res: Resources){
            val orderItemImage: ImageView = contentLayout.findViewById(R.id.orderPartImage)
            val orderItemName: TextView = contentLayout.findViewById(R.id.orderPartName)
            val orderItemWeight: TextView = contentLayout.findViewById(R.id.orderPartWeight)
val orderPartPhoto: String? = orderItem.item.itemPhoto.optString(ctx.getString(R.string.part_photo))

            setOrderedPartLogo(orderItemImage, res, orderPartPhoto)

            val itemPrice: String = String.format("%.2f", orderItem.item.itemPrice)

            val spanText = SpannableString(foodPrice + " €" + "  " + "(" + orderItem.quantity.toString() + "x" + ")" +  orderItem.item.itemName)
            spanText.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(res.getColor(R.color.colorRed)), 0, itemPrice.length + 2, 0)

            orderItemName.text = spanText
            orderItemWeight.text = orderItem.item.itemWeigth
        }



private fun setOrderedPartLogo(orderImageView: ImageView, resources: Resources, imageURL: String?) {

        val bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.no_photo)
        val roundedBitMapDrawable: RoundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, bitmap)
        roundedBitMapDrawable.isCircular = true

        val requestOptions: RequestOptions = RequestOptions()
                .circleCrop()
                .placeholder(roundedBitMapDrawable)
                .error(roundedBitMapDrawable)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH)

        Glide.with(orderImageView.context)
                .load(imageURL)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(orderImageView)
    }
```

Whole Adapter:

```
class OrderListAdapter(private var mActivity: FragmentActivity,
                       private  var orderList: ArrayList<Order>, private var fragment: OrderListFragment):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    private var expandedPosition = -1
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        //order item views
        val orderName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderName)
        val orderWaitTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderWaitTime)
        val orderAddress: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderAddress)
        val orderDate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderDate)

        //details expandable layout
        val orderDetailsExpandable: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderDetails)
        val orderContentLayout: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentLayout)
        val orderLayout: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                    viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // create a new view
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.order_recyclerview_item_layout, parent, false)


        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

        mRecyclerView = recyclerView
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        if (holder is ViewHolder) {
            val res = holder.itemView.context.resources
            val ctx = holder.itemView.context
            orderList[position].let {

                val orderPrice: Int = it.orderJSON.getInt(ctx.getString(R.string.order_total_price))
                val orderSupplierName: String? = it.orderSupplier?.json?.getString(ctx.getString(R.string.sup_name))
                val orderDate: String = it.orderJSON.getString(ctx.getString(R.string.order_date))
                val orderPaymentType: Int = it.orderJSON.getInt(ctx.getString(R.string.order_payment_type))
                var orderPaymentTypeString = "unknown"
                val orderDeliveryType: Int = it.orderJSON.getInt(ctx.getString(R.string.order_delivery_type))
                val orderDeliveryPrice: Int = it.orderJSON.getInt(ctx.getString(R.string.order_delivery_price))
                val orderJSONObject: JSONObject = it.orderJSON
                val orderItemList: ArrayList<OrderedItem> = it.partsList

                //OrderDate -> hours, minutes, day, month, year
                val formattedOrderDate: OrderDate = getOrderDate(orderDate)

                when(orderPaymentType){
                    1 -> orderPaymentTypeString = "credit"
                    2 -> orderPaymentTypeString = "credit"
                    3 -> orderPaymentTypeString = "money"
                    4 -> orderPaymentTypeString = "voucher"
                }


                //set order price, name and type
                val orderPriceString: String = convertCentsToFloat(orderPrice)
                if (orderSupplierName == null){
                    val spannableText = SpannableString(orderPriceString + " €  " + ctx.getString(R.string.default_sup_name) + " - " + orderPaymentTypeString)
                    spannableText.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(res.getColor(R.color.colorRed)), 0, orderPriceString.length + 3, 0)
                    holder.orderName.text = spannableText
                } else {
                    val spannableText = SpannableString(orderPriceString + " €  " + orderSupplierName + " - " + orderPaymentTypeString)
                    spannableText.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(res.getColor(R.color.colorRed)), 0, orderPriceString.length + 3, 0)
                    holder.orderName.text = spannableText
                }

                //set order wait time
                holder.orderWaitTime.text = formattedOrderDate.dateHours + ":" + formattedOrderDate.dateMinutes

                //set order address
                //holder.orderAddress.text = it.orderAddress

                //set order date
                holder.orderDate.text = formattedOrderDate.dateDay + "." + formattedOrderDate.dateMonth + "." + formattedOrderDate.dateYear

                holder.orderContentLayout.removeAllViews()

                //create layout for order items
                for(orderItem in it.itemList){
                    val contentLayout: View = LayoutInflater.from(holder.itemView.context).inflate(R.layout.ordered_list_item_layout, null, false)

                    fillItemView(contentLayout, orderItem, res, ctx)

                    holder.orderContentLayout.addView(contentLayout)
                }

                //create footer delivery
                val deliveryLayout: View = LayoutInflater.from(holder.itemView.context).inflate(R.layout.order_delivery_footer_layout, null, false)
                fillDeliveryFooter(deliveryLayout, orderDeliveryType, orderDeliveryPrice, res, ctx)
                holder.orderContentLayout.addView(deliveryLayout)

                //create footer orderRepeat Button
                val orderRepeatLayout: View = LayoutInflater.from(holder.itemView.context).inflate(R.layout.order_repeat_order_layout, null, false)
                holder.orderContentLayout.addView(orderRepeatLayout)

                orderRepeatLayout.setOnClickListener {
                    fragment.switchToOrderCartActivity(orderItemList)
                }

                //expanding order view on click
                val isExpanded = position == expandedPosition
                holder.orderDetailsExpandable.visibility = if (isExpanded) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
                holder.itemView.isActivated = isExpanded

                holder.orderLayout.setOnClickListener {
                    createLog("expPos ", position.toString())
                    orderList[position].let {
                        if(expandedPosition != position){
                            if(expandedPosition != -1){
                                val myLayout: View? = mRecyclerView.layoutManager.findViewByPosition(expandedPosition)
                                createLog("myLayout", myLayout.toString())
                                createLog("OrderExp", "Expanding layout")
                                if(myLayout != null){
                                    myLayout.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.orderDetails).visibility = View.GONE
                                }
                            }
                            createLog("expPosSet ", position.toString())
                            expandedPosition = position

                        } else {
                            expandedPosition = -1
                        }
                        notifyItemChanged(position)
                        scrollToTop(holder.itemView)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun getItemCount() = orderList.size

    private fun scrollToTop(v: View) {
        val itemToScroll = mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)
        val centerOfScreen = mRecyclerView.width / 2 - v.width / 2
        fragment.getRecyclerViewManager().scrollToPositionWithOffset(itemToScroll, centerOfScreen)
    }

    private fun fillItemView(contentLayout: View, orderItem: OrderedItem, res: Resources){
            val orderItemImage: ImageView = contentLayout.findViewById(R.id.orderPartImage)
            val orderItemName: TextView = contentLayout.findViewById(R.id.orderPartName)
            val orderItemWeight: TextView = contentLayout.findViewById(R.id.orderPartWeight)
            val orderPartPhoto: String? = orderItem.item.itemPhoto.optString(ctx.getString(R.string.part_photo))

            setOrderedPartLogo(orderItemImage, res, orderPartPhoto)

            val itemPrice: String = String.format("%.2f", orderItem.item.itemPrice)

            val spanText = SpannableString(foodPrice + " €" + "  " + "(" + orderItem.quantity.toString() + "x" + ")" +  orderItem.item.itemName)
            spanText.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(res.getColor(R.color.colorRed)), 0, itemPrice.length + 2, 0)

            orderItemName.text = spanText
            orderItemWeight.text = orderItem.item.itemWeigth
        }

    private fun fillDeliveryFooter(deliveryLayout: View, deliveryType: Int, deliveryPrice: Int, res: Resources, ctx: Context){
        val deliveryImageIcon: ImageView = deliveryLayout.findViewById(R.id.deliveryIconImage)
        val deliveryPriceTextView: TextView = deliveryLayout.findViewById(R.id.deliveryLabelText)

        //set delivery icon
        when(deliveryType){
            1 -> deliveryImageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_summary_delivery)
            2 -> deliveryImageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_summary_pickup)
            else -> deliveryImageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.restauracia_no_photo)
        }

        //set delivery price, name label
        val deliveryPriceString: String = convertCentsToFloat(deliveryPrice)

        val deliverySpannable = SpannableString(deliveryPriceString + " €  Doprava / Vyzdvihnutie")
        deliverySpannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(res.getColor(R.color.colorPrice)), 0, deliveryPriceString.length + 2, 0)

        deliveryPriceTextView.text = deliverySpannable
    }

    private fun setOrderedPartLogo(orderImageView: ImageView, resources: Resources, imageURL: String?) {

        val bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.no_photo)
        val roundedBitMapDrawable: RoundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, bitmap)
        roundedBitMapDrawable.isCircular = true

        val requestOptions: RequestOptions = RequestOptions()
                .circleCrop()
                .placeholder(roundedBitMapDrawable)
                .error(roundedBitMapDrawable)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH)

        Glide.with(orderImageView.context)
                .load(imageURL)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(orderImageView)
    }

    private fun convertCentsToFloat(centPrice: Int): String {
        val centOnlyPrice: Int = centPrice % 100
        val euroPrice: Int = (centPrice - centOnlyPrice) / 100

        if (centOnlyPrice < 10) {
            val finalPrice: String = euroPrice.toString() + ".0" + centOnlyPrice.toString()
            return finalPrice
        } else {
            val finalPrice: String = euroPrice.toString() + "." + centOnlyPrice.toString()
            return finalPrice
        }
    }

    private fun getOrderDate(date: String): OrderDate{
        val rawDate: List<String> = date.split("T")

        val dateOnly: String = rawDate[0]
        val dateFormat: List<String> = dateOnly.split("-")

        val timeOnly: String = rawDate[1]
        val timeFormat: List<String> = timeOnly.split(":")

        val finalDate = OrderDate(timeFormat[0], timeFormat[1], dateFormat[2], dateFormat[1], dateFormat[0])

        return finalDate

    }


    fun createLog(tag: String, msg: String){
        Log.i(tag, msg)
    }

    fun refreshOrder(orderListRefreshed: ArrayList<Order>){
        orderList = orderListRefreshed
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        if(AndroidAssets.getInstance(mActivity).orderList.isEmpty()){
            mRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
            fragment.showFooterLayout()
        } else{
            mRecyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            fragment.hideFooterLayout()
        }
        fragment.hideProgressBar()
    }
}
```

Image from AndroidProfiler on Memory Usage(memory usage increased around 25s - this is where I've started scrolling RecyclerView... and after that it dropped).

UPDATE: With better analysis I found out that one SubItem has 2.5MB in memory. If i will have 5 orders containing 20 items each it will allocate 250MB of space in RAM. And this is with Glide caching images.

UPDATE 2: Is there any way how to load only visible views? So as user scrolls it will load new views and top one which will be off the display will be removed from memory. I thought that recyclerview is doing that by default by recycling item layout views.

**UPDATE 3: I've implemented new recyclerview and adapter initialization for inner list. This rv and adapter is initialized when view in onBindViewHolder() is marked as expanded and if it's not expanded RV and Adapter is set to null. So I've implemented Nested RecyclerView. Problem is that my inner recyclerview is not scrolling at all. I have to set scrolling and set RV height to fixed size (for example 400dp), because if I leave it match_parent or wrap_content, it will throw OutOfMemoryError if more than 20 items are inside -> it is not recycling views. How to achieve both recyclerviews to scroll vertically?**

[image]

Layout Visualization:

[image]

Comment: it's not an answer to your question . just an advice . do not use for loop inside onBindHolder() and don't Inflate layouts inside that.it's affect performance. you have to change your approach .

Comment: if you can share your adapter please

Comment: On several cases (especially running on lower API devices) changing from Glide to Picasso solved it for me.

Comment: I have disabled images completely and it still has out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

Your groups (each containing 1000 items) are simply too big.

You should flatten the hierarchy -- that is, expose all the items individually to the RecyclerView. Your adapter will need to override getItemViewType() to return different values for different view types, and you'll need to return different types of view holders depending on the item at each position.

This way, you'll only ever inflate as many views as can fit on the screen (plus a few extra that RecyclerView pre-requests to avoid too much inflation at scroll time).

Comment: Problem is that this is going out of memory with 10 items containing 10 subitems(each). I didn't know that recyclerview performance is that bad.

Comment: 100 views total should not be a problem. I don't think RecyclerView is to blame here. Use Android Studio's built in allocation tracking feature to figure out what allocations are causing you trouble here.

Comment: @martin1337 Have a look at this link https://android.jlelse.eu/get-expandable-recyclerview-in-a-simple-way-8946046b4573 I am trying to use a nested recyclerview any help would be appreciated here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747527/kotlin-recyclerview-data-not-showing