# Kotlin entered value not searching database

Tags: validation, kotlin

We have worked on this code to error trap a value entered in a Edit Text field
When the value is entered correctly we are informed that the entered value does not match
BUT if we select the value from a recycler view list and populate the Edit Text field with the value the search tells us we have a match

Here is the code for the search in the DBHelper

```
    fun getOneName(id: Int): Contact? {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $colId = ?"
    db.rawQuery(selectQuery, arrayOf(id.toString())).use { // .use requires API 16
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            val result = Contact(id = 0,name ="")
            result.id = it.getInt(it.getColumnIndex(colId))
            result.name = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(colName))
            return result
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

We used this for the Model Class our first time using data class as just plain class

```
data class Contact (

var id: Int,
var name: String
```

)

And here is the button click that manages the search

```
        btnGetID.setOnClickListener {
        if(etPerson.text.toString().trim().isNullOrEmpty()){
            message("Enter Contact Name")
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        var numeric = true
        var string = etPerson.text.toString().trim()
        numeric = string.matches(".*\\d+.*".toRegex())
        if(numeric){
            message("No NUMBERS")
            return@setOnClickListener
        }

        val dbManager = DBHelper(this)
        var name = etPerson.text.toString()
        //val contact = dbManager.getOneName(name)
        val contact = dbManager.getOneName(id.toInt())

        if(contact?.name.equals(name)){
            println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! contact ID= "+contact)
            etPerson.setText("The contact name is $name the ID is "+contact?.id.toString())
        }else{
            etPerson.setText("Name NOT = to $name and the ID is "+contact?.id.toString())
        }
    }
```

We know the name Sally is in the DB if we type Sally in the else statement shows Name NOT = bla
If we select Sally from the Recyclerview List the first statement shows The contact name bla bla
Kotlin 1.2.71 API 27

Our question is why is the hand typed name failing if it mataches?

**HERE IS THE CORRECT CODE FOR THE DBHelper**

```
    fun getOneName(name: String): Contact? {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $colName = ?"
    db.rawQuery(selectQuery, arrayOf(name)).use { // .use requires API 16
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            val result = Contact(id = 0,name ="")
            result.id = it.getInt(it.getColumnIndex(colId))
            result.name = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(colName))
            return result
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: In the code you've posted, the query is `val contact = dbManager.getOneName(id.toInt())` and does not depend on the entered user name in any way.

Comment: @yole We changed the code but forgot to change this line of code it works nowval selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $colName = ?"

Comment: Please post the exact code you're using, including the implementation of getOneName() that takes a String parameter.

Comment: @yole Too many parameters Thanks good eyes we looked at this for 4 hours before we posted Question seemed silly

Comment: @yole We would really appreciate if you would look at a question we have bounty on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747527/kotlin-recyclerview-data-not-showing