# Kotlin set value of global variable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, global-variables

We are trying to set the value of a global variable declared in the code below

```
 class MyApplication: Application() {
    var globalVar = 2
}
```

Now we have a Main Activity that has a Edit Text named etPerson we would like to enter a value in etPerson and set the entered value equal to globalVar
Why because we want to make a call to a database function in another Activity
Here is the code that makes the call to the DB

```
    var mApp = MyApplication()
    var intGlobalVar = mApp.globalVar
    println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ globalINT = "+intGlobalVar)
    var ITEM = db.getItem(intGlobalVar)
    println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ITEM "+ITEM?.id+" name "+ITEM?.name)
```

And for clarity here is the DB function

```
    fun getItem(id: Int): Contact? {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $colId = ?"
    db.rawQuery(selectQuery, arrayOf(id.toString())).use {
        // .use requires API 16
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            val result = Contact(0)
            result.id = it.getInt(it.getColumnIndex(colId))
            result.name = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(colName))
            return result
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

So the issue is setting the var globalVar to the value entered in etPerson on the Main Activity
The concept can be accomplished using put and get with intents but that is not our goal here

Our question is how to set the globalVar to the value entered in the Edit Text?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When your app starts one and only one object of the class MyApplication() will be created, so you don't need:

```
var mApp = MyApplication()
```

You can access `MyApplication()` and all its members from everywhere in your app.

Declare a `companion` object in `MyApplication()` and put `globalVar`'s declaration inside:

```
class MyApplication: Application() {    
    companion object {
        var globalVar = 2
    } 

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // initialization code here
    }
}
```

So in your `MainActivity` class or elsewhere you can use `MyApplication.Companion.globalVar` to get or set its value.  
Or you can import the `globalVar` variable in any class like:

```
import yourpackagename.MyApplication.Companion.globalVar
```

and refer to it simply `globalVar`   
 
You also need to declare `MyApplication` in the manifest:

```
  <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to fix the issue We have a ModelClass can we put this companion declaration in the Model?

Comment: This companion declaration must reside in a class that inherits the Application class

Comment: we extended the Contact Class it makes the DBHelper a little crazy but we removed the zero from this line val contact = Contact(0) and all is well WE HAVE a question with a bounty at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747527/kotlin-recyclerview-data-not-showing if you would like to take a look Thanks

Comment: I will, but tomorrow. It's late here and I'm off soon

Comment: Thanks a lot we have been struggling with this for weeks

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to send an Intent :

Target activity or class or object (Reciver):

```
class ReturnActivityIntent private constructor() {
        var data: Intent? = null
        companion object {
            val instance = ReturnActivityIntent()
        }
    }
```

In the MainActivity (Sender)

```
val returnActivityIntent: Notifications.ReturnActivityIntent = Notifications.ReturnActivityIntent.instance
        returnActivityIntent.data = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
```

so you can change or share variables in this way